# Why is this Node/JS function returning an error in the console, but it still works

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I refactored some of my code to clean it up a bit, and it works, but I keep getting an error in the console, and would like to know why.
Old code:

```
app.post("/tickets", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){ 
    let ticket_data = req.body.ticket;
    ticket_data.due_date = moment(ticket_data.due_date, "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate();
    Ticket.create(ticket_data, function(err, newTicket){
    if (err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            //  Redirect
            res.redirect("/tickets");
        }
     });
});
```

New Code:

```
app.post("/tickets", isLoggedIn, async function(req, res){ 
    let ticket_data = req.body.ticket;
    ticket_data.due_date = moment(ticket_data.due_date, "MM-DD-YYYY").toDate(); 

    try {
        await Ticket.create(ticket_data).exec();
    }
    catch (e) {console.log(e);} 
    res.redirect("/tickets");
});
```

It is telling me that this line is not a function:

```
await Ticket.create(ticket_data).exec();
```

Yet it still seems to work, as a new document is still created in the database.  Is there a way I can get the console to stop returning an error with this?  Truthfully, I am still new to the "Try" and "Await" parts of Javascript and am learning as I go, so maybe this is part of what I still don't understand.

I can confirm that when I take that part of the code out completely, I don't get an error, but it doesn't do anything at all.

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You just remove .exec(). You will not get an error.

Comment: Hi, thank you both for your help.  It was the exec() part that was causing it to return an error, and it works without it.  I had originally thought that part was necessary in order to replace the function(err, newTicket... part of my old code, but I guess that it is not necessary.